# How do I achieve mysql like having condition in elastic search?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, having

I want to convert below mysql query in elasticsearch query.

```
SELECT field1,field2, sum(amount)
from tableName 
WHERE field3='somevalue'
GROUP BY field1,field2 
HAVING Sum(amount) > 25000;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported in elasticsearch. See this open issue which documents the issue (and perhaps add your +1 to get them to add this!)

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4404